# Sequelize.js - How to associate a model by two keys from another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have a Users model that includes all of the user information for my application.

```
// model for the users table
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        displayName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }

    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                User.hasMany(models.Session);  // adds key to Sessions for UserID
                User.hasMany(models.Session, {as: "TeammateId"});  // adds key to Sessions as 
            },
        }
    });
    return User;
};
```

The application deals with completing a task with a teammate.  I have another model, Sessions, which tracks the data from each attempt to complete the task.  In each record in Sessions, I have both the UserID as a column as well as the TeammateID for whomever the user was paired up with during the session.  My Sessions model is as follows:

```
// model for the sessions table
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Session = sequelize.define("Session", {
        success: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            default: false
        },
        TeammateId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Session.belongsTo(models.User, { 
                    onDelete: "cascade",
                    foreignKey: {
                        allowNull: false
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return Session;
};
```

I am trying to write a query that will return a record from Sessions (using a UserID as the lookup key) but will also include the teammate's information.  How do I set up/fix my associations so that I can include the teammate's information (using the TeammateID from Sessions joined with the Users model)?

My attempted query is as follows:

```
app.get("[omitted]", function(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.userId;
    db.Session.findAll({
      where: {
        UserId: userId
      },
      include: [db.User]  // this is where i am lost.  it only returns info for the User and not the Teammate
    }).then(function(data){
      res.json(data);
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer.  The key was not in how I made the associations necessarily, but in writing the query's 'include' portion.  Here is my working code:

User model:

```
// model for the users table
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        displayName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }

    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                User.hasMany(models.Session);
                User.hasMany(models.Session, {
                    as: "Teammate"
                }); 
            },
        }
    });
    return User;
};
```

Sessions model:

```
// model for the Sessions table
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Session = sequelize.define("Session", {
        success: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            default: false
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Session.belongsTo(models.User, { 
                    as: "User",
                    onDelete: "cascade",
                    foreignKey: {
                        allowNull: false
                    }
                });
                Session.belongsTo(models.User, { 
                    as: "Teammate",
                    onDelete: "cascade",
                    foreignKey: {
                        allowNull: false
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return Session;
};
```

Query:

```
// route for returning session history with user and teammate information 
app.get("[ommitted]", function(req, res){
  var userId = req.params.userId;
  db.Session.findAll({
    where: {
      UserId: userId
    },
    include: [{
      model: db.User,
      as: "User"
    }, {
      model: db.User,
      as: "Teammate"
    }]
  }).then(function(data){
    // to do: parse the results into a summary easily consumed by the front end.
    res.send(data);
  })
});
```